# Postgres query return unexpected result

Tags: postgresql

Get random row from table foo.

```
create table foo as 
select generate_series(1,1000000) as val;
```

'val' is serial field (not primary). Field dosn't have breaks.

This query might return 0,1,2,3,4... rows and in all rows val has different value. Why?

```
select * from foo where val = 
    (floor(random() * (select max(val) from foo))+1)::int;
```

Slightly change query to

```
select * from foo where val = 
    (select (floor(random() * (select max(val) from foo))+1)::int as v);
```

Result as expected, single random row from table

Comment: Please add some sample data (as *formatted* text!) and the expected output based on that sample data (and possibly include the `create table` statement for the `foo` table)

Comment: the create method is incorrect. use like this`create table bar as select  generate_series(1,1000000)`

Comment: I'm using Postgresql 9.3 64bit on Windows 7, and I can confirm I get the same behaviour. If you do an "explain" on the two queries you get different query plans. Why the first query behaves is it does is beyond me...

Comment: To WIngedPanther. I corrected query.

Comment: Basically problem with last filter. In last case filter looks "Filter: (val = $1)" and it removes always the same amount of rows (1 less then total row count in table). In first case filter looks "  Filter: (val = (floor((random() * ($0)::double precision)))::integer)" and count of removed rows different from time to time.

Comment: @simar: no  under MVCC the query sees a snapshot of the database, with a selfconsistent content including number of rows,

Comment: @WIngedPanther: You was right about different plans. My fault, I didn't pay attention to planner message. Planner clearly state what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's random function is [volatile](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/xfunc-volatility.html) which means it may return diferent values every time it is evaluated,  your first query compares a different random number with each row of the table, your second computes a single random value and compares every row with that.

suppose you want a shuffled deck of cards:

```
select * from deck_of_cards order by random();
```

or maybe yahtzee us more your thing:

```
select floor(random()*6)+1::int from generate_series (1,6);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the idea why it happens, and I understood what happens in execution plan. Since function is mutable then in first case  filter step has to check match of val field with new random value on every row. Basically on 1000000 rows, there is 1 chance from 1000000 when generated value and field value will match (if consider val field has no gaps/breaks). That is why this query return different amount of rows from 0 to 5, but statistically around 1 value match.

Comment: I made wrap around random to make immutable function and planner chose as expected "good" behavior